# How can I try old UNIX versions?

Tags: historical-unix

I want to try old versions of UNIX for fun, but I don't know where to get them. Is there a way to download them?

Comment: which versions are you talking about? ... are those versions open source?

Comment: @jsotola Whatever, but I'm most interested in the first one.

Comment: do you have the hardware to run it on? ... I'm pretty sure that it would not run on an intel platform

Comment: @jsotola I want to run it on a QEMU/KVM virtual machine, so it will probaly work.

Comment: Which Unix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unix_history-simple.svg

Comment: i am not so sure that QEMU will emulate a DEC minicomputer

Answer (score 2):

In short, download them from TUHS/PUPS and run them on SIMH.

See https://minnie.tuhs.org/PUPS/pupsfaq.html, [https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ancient/](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/ancient/) and https://unixarchive.cn-k.de/Documentation/PUPS/pupsfaq.html#emulators

Comment: Those three links are woefully out of date and are marked "This page and everything under PUPS/ is kept to preserve the historical record. It's all out of date".  Use https://www.tuhs.org/ instead (The Unix Heritage Society.)